# Weird KRL foreach behavior

Tags: krl

I've been getting some odd behavior using a foreach today. I have a `dataset` that's pulling in a JSON document. Part of it is an array, which I `pick()` out and send to the foreach. Here's my global block:

```
global {
  dataset appserver <- "http://imaj-app.lddi.org:8010/list/popular" cachable for 1 hour;
  popular = appserver.pick("$..images")
}
```

There's one rule first that sets up the page. It looks like this:

```
rule setup {
  select when web pageview "www\.google\.com"

  pre {
    imagelist = <<
      <div id="462popular" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:450px">
        <p>Popular images from the CS 462 <a href="http://imaj-web.lddi.org/">Image Project</a></p>
        <span class="image"></span>
      </div>
    >>;
  }

  prepend('#footer', imagelist);
}
```

And here's the rule that's not working:

```
rule images {
  select when web pageview "www\.google\.com"
  foreach popular setting (image)

  pre {
    thumburl = image.pick("$..thumburl");
    viewurl = "http://imaj-web.lddi.org/view?imagekey=" + image.pick("$..imagekey");
    html = <<
      <span class="image"><a href="#{viewurl}"><img src="#{thumburl}" style="border:none"/></a></span>
    >>;
  }

  after('#462popular .image', html);
}
```

I get something like this (notice how small the scrollbar thumb is):

[image: Lots of images]

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a recursion problem with your html structure and your after selector to insert new content.

Your selector for inserting new content is

```
#462popular .image
```

which means that the contents of `html` will be inserted after every element with the class of image inside an element with the id of #462popular.

Inside the html that you are inserting you have an element with the class name of image which means you are multiplying the number of elements with the class of image inside #462popular every time you go through the loop.

: )

Comment: Oh, duh! I should have noticed that. :)